# Install postgres-client-13 on debian buster

Tags: postgresql, debian-buster

I need to run pg_dump from a Node.js docker image (node:16-buster) to a postgres 13.6 docker image. The problem is that for Buster version the only package available for postgresql-client is 11 and I get this messages when trying to run pg:dump.

```
pg_dump: server version: 13.6; pg_dump version: 11.15 (Debian 11.18-0+deb10u1)
pg_dump: aborting because of server version mismatch
```

How can I install postgresql-client-13 on Buster?

Comment: Is pg_dump not installed in the docker image you are dumping to? If you need it on the host then it should be available from the PostgreSQL team itself. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt

Comment: But i am running pg_dump from a docker container to the Postgres container. So I need to install postgresql-client in the container that is running Nodejs.

Comment: Well, it can run anywhere, so long as it can connect to the database installations you want it to talk to. And I think the standard postgresql docker image includes pg_dump - I certainly seem to have it here.

Comment: Sure, but the official Node.js image does not have installed postgres-client so I need to install it when i build my own app image based on nodejs:16-buster

Comment: You said `to a postgres 13.6 docker image` - that container will have pg_dump (and the right version too of course). So long as the second container can see the first one, that should work fine.

Comment: Maybe i am doing wrong but in the nodeJs app I spawn a command (pgdump) pointing in the host argument to the postgres container so I need pgdump in the nodejs container not in the postgres container.

Comment: Or, as I said, run pg_dump from the postgres container and point it at node-js. I don't understand why you seem so opposed to that.

Comment: I am not opposed but I had it working this way and I dont want to change the approach by now. Maybe in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out that for buster postgres-client-13 is not available but it is for bullseye.

So I upgraded to Node:18-bullseye. I hope every thing goes right with this update.

Comment: and now 15 is not available.